# Есть 3 кнопки, при каждом клике открывается описание данной кнопки, как убрать...

Tags: jquery

Как убрать предыдущую запись, когда мы кликаем по другой кнопке, подскажите, есть скрипт при клике, что бы открывалось описание, может его как то можно доработать? подскажите

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.span12 ul li a').on('click', function(e){
     $(this).siblings('span').toggle();
     e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.span12 ul li a').on('click', function(e) {

         // Находим все span в соседених li и скрываем их
         $(this).closest('li').siblings('li').find('span').hide();

         $(this).siblings('span').toggle();

         e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/sCS4a/